# Powershell Script Checker

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I would like to comprise a powershell script that checks for an server name with SQL- in the suffix. one of my environments is called 73Test within this environment you have virtual servers named ASNAV-SQL-73-01 & ASNAV-SQL-73-02. I want my scrip[t to extract this from my 30 environments?

I hope this is easier to understand.

Regards,

Joe

Comment: Could you edit the question and elaborate on what you mean with "check the SQL instances"?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you extracting the names from(are you using VMWare or HyperV or some other hypervisor?) This will work on both PowerCLI(VMWare) and HyperV

```
get-vm *sql*
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Raf, we are using the Remote Desktop Connection Manager to remote onto the Virtual Environments. We are using VMWare. for my powershell window i use ConEmu.

Comment: Download [PowerCLI](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VSP510-PCLI-510&productId=285), run it, and you will be able to run commands like `get-vm *sql*`.

Comment: Hi Raf,
PowerCLI C:\Windows\system32> Connect-VIServer

cmdlet Connect-VIServer at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Server[0]: ASNAV-DEVSQL-24
Server[1]: ASNAV-DEVSQL-27


PowerCLI C:\Windows\system32> Connect-VIServer
cmdlet Connect-VIServer at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Server[0]: ASNAV-DEVSQL-24
Server[1]: ASNAV-DEVSQL-27
Server[2]:
Connect-VIServer : 04/02/2014 13:14:37    Connect-VIServer        Network
connectivity error occured. Please verify that the network address and port
are correct.

Comment: So basically the error in the previous message i showing the names of two servers but it errors to connect.

Comment: You need to connect to your vCenter box(or directly to esxi if you don't have vcenter) when running `Connect-VIServer` , only then you run `get-vm *sql*`.  

I suggest you read this tutorial [http://www.petri.co.il/vmware-vsphere-powercli-getting-started.htm](http://www.petri.co.il/vmware-vsphere-powercli-getting-started.htm)

Comment: Hi Raf, Does vcenter server need to be installed on the box im trying to query?

Comment: You need to connect to your management endpoint which will be either vCenter or esxi(if you don't have a vCenter server). So you would run `Connect-VIServer _vcenterIpAddressOrName_` or `Connect-VIServer _esxiIpAddressOrName_` and then run other cmdlets like `get-vm`.

Comment: Hi Raf, That hasnt worked at all do you have an example of what the output should look like

Comment: I refer you to my previous comment and urge you to familiarise yourself with the basics. Here is the link again, it has another link to an article which guides you through setting powerCLI up
[http://www.petri.co.il/vmware-vsphere-powercli-getting-started.htm](http://www.petri.co.il/vmware-vsphere-powercli-getting-started.htm)

Comment: Hi Raf, I have tried to the steps as suggested and it still doesnt work?

Comment: Which part doesn't work and what is the error message? What are you connecting to(vcenter or esxi) and what versions are you running?